# How to print a matrix partialy in python

Tags: python, printing, matrix

I have a numeric square matrix, and want to print only a part of the data like:

I have:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
[6, 7, 2, 0, 0]
[4, 5, 8, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And I want to print just:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[6, 7, 2]
[4, 5, 8]
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Did you try doing this on your own? Include some code in your question to show what you've already attempted, and explain where exactly you're stuck or something's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using NumPy (and you should be), just slice it:

```
print a[:3, :3]
```